# What are the requirements to deploy firebase functions?

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to deploy a very simple function to firebase functions through the index.ts file.

the deployment command used is:
`firebase deploy --only functions`

this is the index.ts file:

```
import { getDatabase, ref, get, child } from "firebase/database";

import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as cors from "cors";
import * as express from "express";
import * as bodyParser from "body-parser";

import { AnyExercise, Workout } from "./types";

const app = express();

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// Automatically allow cross-origin requests
app.use(cors({ origin: true }));

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const dbRef = ref(getDatabase());

app.get("/workouts/:userId", (req, res) => {
  get(child(dbRef, `workouts/${req.params.userId}`))
    .then((snapshot) => {
      if (snapshot.exists()) {
        console.log("workouts", snapshot.val());
        return snapshot.val();
      } else {
        console.log("No data available");
        return null;
      }
    })
    .then((workouts: Record<Workout["id"], Workout>) => {
      if (!workouts) {
        res.send({ workoutObj: {}, exerciseListByWorkout: {} });
      }
      get(child(dbRef, "exercises")).then((snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
          const exercises: Record<AnyExercise["id"], AnyExercise> =
            snapshot.val();
          console.log("exercises", exercises);
          const mappedExercises: Record<Workout["id"], AnyExercise[]> = {};
          Object.values(workouts).forEach((workout) => {
            const exList: any[] = [];
            workout.exerciseList?.forEach((exId) => {
              const ex = exercises && exercises[exId];
              if (ex) {
                exList.push(ex);
              }
            });
            mappedExercises[workout.id] = exList;
          });
          res.send({ workoutObj: [], exerciseListByWorkout: mappedExercises });
        } else {
          console.log("No data available");
          res.send({ workoutObj: workouts, exerciseListByWorkout: {} });
        }
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
      res.send(error);
    });
});

// Expose Express API as a single Cloud Function:
export const api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

this is the error that I am getting when i try to deploy it:

```
Error: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from 
function source: FirebaseError: Firebase: Need to provide options, when not being deployed 
to hosting via source. (app/no-options).
```

I just don't understand what the error is even saying. what options is the message talking about in this context that i need to provide?

Comment: Have you added the SDK and initialized the realtime database first? Please check this documentation on [realtime database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start).

Comment: Did my previous comment address your concern?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Realtime Database JS SDK and initialize Realtime Database first. Based on this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start#add_the_js_sdk_and_initialize):

> You must specify your Realtime Database URL when initializing the JavaScript SDK.
>
> You can find your Realtime Database URL in the Realtime Database section of the Firebase console. Depending on the location of the database, the database URL will be in one of the following forms:
>
> - https://[DATABASE_NAME].firebaseio.com (for databases in us-central1)
> - https://[DATABASE_NAME].[REGION.firebasedatabase.app (for databases in all other locations)

Initialize the SDK using the following code snippet:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database";

// TODO: Replace the following with your app's Firebase project configuration
// See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/learn-more#config-object
const firebaseConfig = {
  // ...
  // The value of `databaseURL` depends on the location of the database
  databaseURL: "https://[DATABASE_NAME].firebaseio.com",
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


// Initialize Realtime Database and get a reference to the service
const database = getDatabase(app);
```